# iOS: Retrieving element from parsed Data in NSMutableArray

Tags: xml-parsing, nsmutablearray

I am trying to achieve the following:

My App parses an XML-File, built like this:

```
<product>
 <id>3482</id>
 <title>Product 1</title>
 <number>1</number>
 <description>Text</description>
</product>

<product>
 <id>4743</id>
 <title>Product 2</title>
 <number>2</number>
 <description>Text</description>
</product>

<product>
 <id>3864</id>
 <title>Product 3</title>
 <number>3</number>
 <description>Text</description>
</product>
```

There are 20 products in the XML. Everything works fine. The parser saves all data in a NSMutableArray. Now I'd like to retrieve just all 20 titles of the products from this NSMutableArray.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clarification of which parser you are using would be useful. Presumably the items are stored as an array of dictionaries, with the xml attributes as the keys. If this is the case, to get the id of the first object, you would do something like:

```
[objectArray[0] valueForKey:@"id"];
```